# What does this third Azure Token lifetime refer to?

Tags: azure, token, access-token, refresh-token, azure-authentication

I get idtoken, access and refresh tokens lifetimes, what is the final lifetime input in Tokens refers to?

[image]
thank you

Comment: I believe this is the refresh token max inactive time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the sliding window lifetime to your refresh token. **After this time period elapses the user is forced to re-authenticate, irrespective of the validity period of the most recent refresh token acquired by the app.**

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-manage-sso-and-token-config